# C# Arrays - Using them to store game level

Tags: c#

I'm making a 2D tile based game. I use a 2D jagged array to store an integer, and the renderer then draws a certain image depending on what that integer is. I have this part of my code working, however I've come to a point where I'm not sure how to proceed next.

As the player goes on through the game, I need to be able to store information about every cell in the 2D array, such as the light level, or the number of times the user has clicked that cell, or the rotation value of the image in that cell, or the alpha level for that image, etc etc.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create a 2D array like I have done previously, for each piece of information I'm using. So for example:

```
AlphaLevel[][]
NumberOfTimesClicked[][]
```

And then if I needed (for example) to check the number of times the user has clicked the cell 5,5 I can do NumberOfTimesClicked[5][5] or if I needed to set the rotation I could do SetRotation[5][5] = 90.

The thing I'm not sure about is how efficient this is, having an array for each piece of information doesn't seem that memory efficient.

Is the idea I have a good solution, or is there a better way I haven't thought about?

Any advice would be great!
Thanks

Comment: You might find the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) helpful.

Comment: ["1. Make it work. 2. Make it work right. 3. Make it work fast."](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast)  You are trying to start at step 3.  Start at step 1, and optimize as you discover bottlenecks.

Answer (score 22):

Make a `Tile` object that has the information, like `AlphaLevel` and `NumberOfTimesClicked`, and make a jagged array of those. Then, you only need one jagged array to hold all of your information, and it's organized more nicely, since you can easily find all the properties a `Tile` has.

If you're interested in memory optimization, NPSF3000 is correct in saying structs will be marginally better. Make sure you're familiar with how value and reference types differ before using them.

Storing data in a smaller format is always going to be bigger than not storing data at all. In addition to working to compress your current data as much as possible, look at ways of storing old data you won't need to disk, or discarding data you can generate procedurally later.

One last note: are you sure you need to compress it? When I worked on 2D tile systems in the past, I found that I was actually storing some extra data so I could improve speed, because I wasn't actually using that much memory. Run some numbers to make sure you're actually using enough memory for optimizations to be worth it.

Comment: This is a correct approach for C#. Using objects to store each tile's data makes more sense and will be more efficient than multidimensional arrays for tile data. Also, I would use C# generic collections instead of jagged arrays. Generally, generic collections are managed much more efficiently in C#.

Comment: @NickZimmerman I suspect you're wrong on both counts.  Objects are not very efficient compared to arrays of data (more space needed, worse on cache, slower etc.).  Furthermore I can't see how a 'generic collection' would be faster than an jagged array as a rule.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Generic collections are often faster *for their intended purpose*. For instance, `Dictionary` is very fast for lookups from a key, compared to searching an array for an object/struct with the same key, due to its internal hashing. You're right, though, that they're not faster as a rule; there's no catch all solution. It's just a case of looking at your use case and seeing what fits it best.

Comment: @MikePrecup exactly.  I agree that Generic collections may be faster for specific use-cases (as might other collections/algorithms in general) but that's not 'as a rule'.  Furthermore in this particular instance I can't think of a single inbuilt collection that'd be faster given the description of the problem - a (likely) fixed range of contiguous values, accessed via integer index.

Comment: @MikePrecup Lastly, regardless of how much better a collection can be when used correctly, I fail to see how they are 'managed much more efficiently in C#' - if anything the reverse is true with lots of array specific optimisations in the compiler/s.  TL;DR the shred of truth behind Nicks statements is covered by significant mistakes in his explanation and application.

Comment: @NPSF3000 Agreed on all points. The only thing I can think of that would work better would be custom data structures, such as the chunk based systems common in these types of games.

Answer (score 5):

> The thing I'm not sure about is how efficient this is, having an array
>   for each piece of information doesn't seem that memory efficient.

Short Answer:  You could use Structs as an alternative - it'd get rid of the additional arrays by simply 'storing everything together'.

---

Long Answer:

An array's representation is something like the following:
    `Header:Data`
where the header is a 4 byte Int32.

Currently your storage might look something like this:

```
IIII:B:B:B  //Byte array (e.g. alpha level)
IIII:SS:SS:SS  //Short array (e.g. num times clicked)
IIII:B:B:B  //Byte array
```

Where I, B and S represent a byte of an Int, Byte and Short respectively.  With Struct's you can store it all together - like so:

```
IIII:BSSB:BSSB:BSSB
```

If you use classes instead it looks very different, as a class is stored in an array as a reference to the location of the data:

```
IIII:RRRR:RRRR:RRRR
BSSB  //These can be stored anywhere in memory
BSSB  //These can be stored anywhere in memory
BSSB  //These can be stored anywhere in memory
```

So while a struct can save some memory, it's not a lot.  Using classes instead will actually cost you memory!  However the memory it uses does not have to be contiguous which can help when storing *lots* of large groups of data (e.g. totalling 1GB+) esp. on 32 bit machines... however that's a discussion for another day.

Of course this purely talks about memory size efficiency, if your workload does computation on a field by field basis, then individual arrays are going to be far more cache friendly - and therefor efficient.  Conversely, if you tend to do computation on a tile by tile basis then the reverse is true.  Classes are inefficient for raw storage, but if they fit your coding paradigm may make development much easier.  Furthermore classes are good when many objects need a reference to the *same* data - which can even save memory by reducing duplicates!

Hope this helps, as you can see a good understanding of the fundamentals helps a bit.  The most important thing however is to value your time, and if/when performance becomes an issue test and benchmark for *yourself!*

Disclaimer:  Written early in morning, may be wrong/have omissions etc.

Comment: I'm not sure the rules the C# follows, but I know that in GCC you get no guarantee about struct data being tightly packed. It sometimes adds padding in the struct between the data if it thinks the code can be made faster by doing so. I doubt it will affect the OP, I'm just leaving this in case someone is doing something more memory focused.

Comment: @MikePrecup Good point.  If you were to go down that route, and problems arose, I'd look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx and similar.

Answer (score 0):

Four approaches are:

- Define a jagged array for each attribute possessed by each map cell
- Combine multiple cell attributes into a structure type (expose public fields rather than properties for best performance and semantics), and define a jagged array of those
- Define an immutable class type class type which holds multiple cell attributes, define a jagged array of those, and initialize all elements with a default instance.
- Define a mutable class type which holds multiple cell attribute, define a jagged array of those, initialize every element of the array to refer to a distinct object instance, and never write to the array again (merely mutate the instances to which it holds references).

If there are certain groups of attributes that will likely be accessed close together and others that won't, one may achieve optimal performance by using the second approach, grouping things that often go together.  If there are certain combinations of attribute values which will occur much more often than others, it may make sense to combine those particular attributes into an immutable class.  Generally, though, for an internal data type my preference would be to use a jagged array of an exposed-field structure type.

For this application, the mantra that structures should be immutable is *just plain wrong*.  The semantics of mutable structures are different from those of classes; anyone who doesn't understand that may find them confusing.  That does not mean, however, that one should avoid using structures.  Rather, it means that anyone who wants to be a good programmer should understand how structures work.  All exposed-field structures behave the same way, and learning how all such structures behave should not take any longer than learning how to use a typical Framework class.